# How to change Laravel Jetstream components path

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-jetstream

I wanna change default Jetstream components after publishing views (`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views`) from **resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components** for example to **resources/views/path/to/jet/comps**

Comment: You can publish the views https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/stacks/livewire.html#components which will move them out of vendor.

Comment: Did you read my question meticulous? @MichaelMano

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by copying the components from laravel/jetstream and putting them wherever you like within your app.

Then you need to alias the jetstream class with your own version.

What I did was copy all components from

```
/vendor/laravel/jetstream/src/Http/livewire/
```

Copied them to

```
/app/Http/Livewire/
```

And changed the namespaces in components to

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;`
```

Then open your app/Providers/JetstreamSrviceProvider.php or if you would prefer you can create your own service provider or use AppServiceProvider.php.

Add the following before the class definition but after the namespace definition:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;
```

Then in the register method add this:

```
            $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\ApiTokenManager', 'App\Http\Livewire\ApiTokenManager');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\CreateTeamForm', 'App\Http\Livewire\CreateTeamForm');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\DeleteTeamForm', 'App\Http\Livewire\DeleteTeamForm');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\DeleteUserForm', 'App\Http\Livewire\DeleteUserForm');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\LogoutOtherBrowserSessionsForm', 'App\Http\Livewire\LogoutOtherBrowserSessionsForm');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\NavigationDropdown', 'App\Http\Livewire\NavigationDropdown');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\TeamMemberManager', 'App\Http\Livewire\TeamMemberManager');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\TwoFactorAuthenticationForm', 'App\Http\Livewire\TwoFactorAuthenticationForm');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\UpdatePasswordForm', 'App\Http\Livewire\UpdatePasswordForm');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\UpdateProfileInformationForm', 'App\Http\Livewire\UpdateProfileInformationForm');
            $loader->alias('Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Livewire\UpdateTeamNameForm', 'App\Http\Livewire\UpdateTeamNameForm');
```

Then run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

You can then open your version of the components and modify the view paths if you prefer or whatever else it is you were looking to do.

I have built a CMS as a package and done exactly this from a package which works well and means we can ship the package with our own views and updated components.